# Theorem A3 in Asymptotic properties of MLE for the i.n.i.d. case

Tags: mathematical-statistics, maximum-likelihood

Can someone explain to me why in the theorem below (case in $R^1$)

$$\lim \inf I(A\cap B(u))|X_k(u)| \leq I(A\cap B)|X_k|$$

Full text of proof: http://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.aoms/1177693066, page 1987

Theorem A3:
Let U be a subset of $\mathcal{R}$. If $\{X_k(u): k=1,2,..., u \in U \} $ is ui (uniformly integrable) and $\lim\limits_{u \rightarrow u_0} X_k(u)=X_k$ as $u \rightarrow u_0$ a.s. [P], then {$X_k: k=1,2,... $} is ui.

Proof (the first part):
Choose $M$ so large that:
$\int_{|X_k(u)>M|}|X_k(u)|dP<\epsilon$

Holding $k$ fixed, let:

\begin{align}
A    &= \{\lim X_k(u) = X_k \ as \ u \rightarrow u_0\}\\
B(u) &= \{|X_k(u)|>M\}\\
B    &= \{|X_k|>M\}
\end{align}

For any $F \in \mathcal{F}$, let $I(F)$ denote the indicator random variable associated with $F$. It is then clear (this is the part I don't understand why it is clear) that as $u \rightarrow u_0$

$$\lim \inf I(A\cap B(u))|X_k(u)| \geq I(A\cap B)|X_k|$$

Comment: Presumably "ui" means *uniformly integrable.*

Answer (score 0):

We know that

> if $\lim_{u\to u_0}g(u)=\ell $ then 
>   $\liminf_{u\to u_0}f(u)g(u)=\ell\liminf_{u\to u_0}f(u)$.

The wanted inequality is clear if $\omega$ is not in $A$; if $\omega\in A$ then we use the highlighted claim to be reduced to prove that $\liminf_{u\to u_0}\mathbf 1\left(B\left(u\right)\right)(\omega)\geqslant\mathbf 1\left(B \right)(\omega)$. If $\omega$ is not in $B$, the inequality is clear; otherwise we know that $\left\lvert X_k\left(\omega\right)\right\rvert\gt M$ hence there exists a $\delta\gt 0$ such that $\left\lvert X_k\left(u\right)\left(\omega\right)\right\rvert\gt M$ for $u$ such that $\left\lvert u-u_0\right\rvert\lt \delta$. For these $u$, $\omega$ belongs to $B(u)$.